# How to uninstall node js on centos 7

Tags: node.js, linux, centos7

I tried to all code command line ssh

```
rm -r bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node.1
```

---

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

---

```
sudo make uninstall
```

---

```
./configure then sudo make uninstall
```

---

```
sudo npm rm npm -g
```

---

```
sudo yum remove nodejs
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf bin/node bin/node-waf include/node lib/node lib/pkgconfig/nodejs.pc share/man/man1/node
```

---

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules
```

---

```
brew uninstall node
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/{npm*,node*,man1/node*}
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp
```

---

```
sudo rm -rf /npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp
```

---

```
node
sudo make uninstall
```

---

and remove npm in bin dir

---

But when `node --version` still show `v6.3.1`

How can i do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

Comment: i tried all code but not work.